# How do I properly refresh a div, with jquery/ajax, that contains a form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit, reload

I've gotten pretty far already writing out all my code. I'm not entirely sure if you would need to see it to get an idea.

Basically I'm using the basic:

```
$("#formToLoadPageInto").load("thePageToLoad.php").fadeIn("fast");
```

Now, that works and all, but the page loaded has a form. It works the first time (submits the form) before having to use that load, but afterwards (when it's reloaded with that code) the form on the page that was reloaded doesn't submit anymore.
I've read that you shouldn't place things like that in the `$(document).ready(function(){` body, but it actually remained outside of that this whole time. So I'm really not sure what could be wrong.

Everything is based on not refreshing the page.. I've managed to accomplish that so far, but this problem (and a few related) are holding me back! Hope someone can help me out..

**EDIT:**

Maybe this will help:

I have 2 different divs - "post comment" and "posted comments".

The post comment div has a form to submit a comment. It's a php page loaded into a div. This works fine. When the form is submitted, it uses this code:

```
$("#newpost").validate({
        debug: false,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('postthought.php', $("#newpost").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#hideload').html(data);
            });
        }
});
```

After that runs, I try to reload the posted comments div (which contains a form, in php, that loads all the posted comments to view and delete) with the

```
$("#formToLoadPageInto").load("thePageToLoad.php").fadeIn("fast");
```

as stated before. It works and shows the new content, but I can't use the form on THIS page to view or delete the comments..

Hope that's not too confusing..

Comment: Well, does the content from your ajax response contain a form too? Otherwise, the form is going to get clobbered.

Comment: Are you loading an entire page into `"#formToLoadPageInto"`? And is `"#formToLoadPageInto"` a `<form>` element as the ID suggests? In other words, are you placing a `<form>` inside a `<form>`?

Comment: No the form isn't being reloaded into the form, it's being reloaded into the div..

Answer (score 0):

If the form itself is being replaced you'll either need to reapply the handler for the form submission or use a handler that is delegated to an element (perhaps the document itself) that isn't being replaced.

```
$('#formToLoadPageInto').on('submit','form', function() {
     ... do submission...
     $('#formToLoadPageInto').load('thePageToLoad.php').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#formToLoadPageInto").empty().load("thePageToLoad.php?" + Math.random()).fadeIn("fast");
```

Comment: @user1162534 random number to prevent caching

Comment: Should'nt there be a questionmark in there somewhere, preferably between the php extension and the random number?

Comment: I've been keeping away from the "php?=" whatever at the end of the url. So far so good, I'd like to keep it that way. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the "posted comments" div (which contains a new form for viewing/editing) is inserted into the DOM just fine, but that you aren't initializing its JavaScript controls.

For example, if the form has a list of comments and an "edit" button for each one, something like this in the DOM ready handler will work:

```
$('#formToLoadPageInto').on('click','form input[name="editButton"]', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var formData = {
        commentID: $this.val(), 
        commentBody: $this.siblings('textarea').text()
    };
    $.post('editComment.php', formData, function(response) {
        //....
    });
});
```

(This uses delegation to "pre-wire" a single event handler to all current and subsequently inserted controls matching the given selector.)